# requests getting SSLError due to certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am using Python 2.7.3, Requests version 2.7.0.  I have setup a simple HTTPS server using a self signed certificate.  I can run the following script on my Windows fine.  But I am unable to do the same on an embedded device.  On the embedded device I have no problem with http get or https with verify=False.

```
import requests
url = 'https://192.168.3.4:8002'
requests.get(url, verify='/home/root/server.crt')
```

The error statement:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    requests.get(url, verify='/home/root/server.crt')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno bad handshake] [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Your error message doesn't include the actual error statement. Can you ensure you've added the entire error?

Comment: @JamieCounsell Thanks for pointing this out.  I have updated the  error statement.

Comment: Is there the same version of python and requests on both systems? And the same contents in `/home/root/server.crt`. And the same version of openssl used by python?

Comment: Same server.crt and requests (2.7.0) version.  On Windows, I am running python 2.7.10; whereas on the embedded device I am running 2.7.3.

With openssl, on the embedded: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013; on the Windows: OpenSSL 0.9.81 5 Nov 2009

Comment: I have solved the problem.  The problem has nothing to do requests.  It turns out that while the self-signed certificate was generated on the server correctly, the client clock is at least a few months old.  Once I have synced up the client's clock, the problem is fixed.